# Do leaderboard sets (in Game Center) allow 500 unique leaderboards?

Tags: ios, leaderboards, game-center

The [Game Kit Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKit_Guide.pdf) for iOS claims:

> The number of different leaderboards allowed increases to 500
>   leaderboards per game when leaderboard sets have been
>   enabled...Leaderboard sets offer developers the ability to combine
>   several leaderboards into a single group.

But their example (see image below) implies that a single leaderboard is placed into multiple leaderboard sets. Is that the only way to be able to use the full 500 leaderboards? by combining the same leaderboard into multiple sets? I want to be able to have 500 unique leaderboards that are not duplicated between sets. Is this possible?

[image: Leaderboard sets]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you need to share leaderboards between sets to reach the 500 limit. Each leaderboard could be contained in only one set, for example.

Later in [the same document you quoted](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html), it says "You can define up to 100 different leaderboard sets for your game. Each leaderboard set can contain up to 100 leaderboards with a maximum of 500 leaderboards for your game. You choose which leaderboards are placed inside of each leaderboard set. Games that don’t use leaderboard sets are limited to 100 leaderboards."

I think that's pretty clear, but feel free to ask any follow-up questions!

Comment: I guess its pretty clear, they simply say 500 is the limit if using Leaderboard Sets and don't specify any restrictions so it must be the case. Thanks!